# Hide and Show li attribute in different html with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i hide and show li attrribute if i click another html

here's the html

```
    <li id="editroutes">
        <a  class="navbar-brand-name" href="/home/update">
            <img class="img-responsive showimage" src="/p/image/edit_icon.png">Edit
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="doneroutes">
        <a class="navbar-brand-name" href="/home">
            <img class="img-responsive hideimage" src="/p/image/cross_check.png">Done
        </a>
    </li>
```

and i don't know how to get this function if i wan to click Edit so the list Edit will hide and it will show the list Done in other html so any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Another html means another page?

Comment: yeah another pages sir

Comment: So you want a behaviour such that, clicking in page, something happends in another page? That's not possible with simple html and javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#editButton').click(function() {
  $('#editroutes').toggle();
  $('#doneroutes').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not able to understand the meaning of `another HTML`. But if you want to hide and show the `<li>` on click of the links you can try this **:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#editroutes").click(function(){  
    $("#editroutes").hide();
    $("#doneroutes").show();
  });
  $("#doneroutes").click(function(){  
    $("#doneroutes").hide();
    $("#editroutes").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="editroutes">
    <a  class="navbar-brand-name" href="/home/update">
        <img class="img-responsive showimage" src="/p/image/edit_icon.png">Edit
    </a>
</li>
<li id="doneroutes">
    <a class="navbar-brand-name" href="/home">
        <img class="img-responsive hideimage" src="/p/image/cross_check.png">Done
    </a>
</li>
```